# Is it correct to say divorce decree of my previous marriage?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Would it be correct to say "I have attached the divorce decree of my previous marriage"?

Comment: It is more usual to talk about the 'decree nisi' and the decree absolute'. I take it that you mean you are attaching the decree absolute of your divorce. A divorce, in and of itself, is not a decree. The absolute decree refers to the dissolution of the union.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are remarried now, yes.  *Previous marriage* implies that there is a current marriage.  If you are not remarried, it would simply be *"I have attached my divorce decree"*.